# Can't run tmux in Arch Linux VM

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, tmux, archlinux, multiplexing

So I have installed tmux in Arch 2016.06.01. I am connected via SSH. When trying to run the program, I get this response:

tmux: invalid LC_ALL, LC,TYPE or LANG

Other programs open fine on this VM. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried resetting `LC_ALL`?

Comment: Well, you should start with examining the contents of the environment variables it mentions, to see where the problem actually is (e.g. `echo $LC_ALL`). One or more of the variables will need to be modified appropriately - either set to a valid value or unset completely...

Comment: I uncommented my locale in the `/etc/locale.gen` file and then generated it with `locale-gen`. Now tmux runs. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I uncommented my locale in the `/etc/locale.gen` file and then generated it with `locale-gen`. Now tmux runs.